# iis 6: Asp extension and html extension

Tags: asp.net, iis

Suppose to have some asp code into a file Main.asp and suppose you want to include this file into other files with .htm extension.
I tried to create a new file mapping for *.htm (for asp.dll) in IIS 6.2 on windows 8.1, but this does not work.
I also try to include .asp file in a file with .htm extension (SSI allowed for .htm extension). The file is included but cannot <%> code  does not execute anymore.

I tried to create a masterpage and then to use

So, to have mixed asp code and simple html text in a page with .htm extension seems impossible.

Any suggestion?

Comment: it is, impossible. asp code needs to be compiled before sending it to the client. you can however, use an iframe that will host an aspx page, or use ajax to pull an aspx page from the server which will get compiled by the server and then you can stick it whenever on your page you want.

Comment: Ok, the first solution with iframe is the one i use since now. The second one with aiax executing from server side never tried. Can you suggest to me some sample code somewhere? Thanks

Comment: the ajax is not executed on server side. you perform ajax from clientside as usual, but when you retrieve the aspx page it will get compiled before its sent as a response to the ajax call, and then you can stick the response in a div somewhere on your page.